# Can't find out cause of Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, metamask

## What I want to do

I'm trying to use Next.js to connect to Metamask in a local environment to get the addresses and balances of accounts.

So first, I am trying to implement a simple UI where I can place a "wallet button" to connect to Metamask and get Accounts object by pressing it.

## My Code

Layout.jsx mounted on index.jsx, which is implemented by ConnectWallet.jsx and ConnectMetamaskButton.jsx as shown below,

`Layout.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ConnectWallet from "./ConnectWallet";


export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/js/all.min.js"></script>
            <header className="text-gray-100 bg-gray-900 body-font shadow w-full">
                <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
                    <nav className="flex lg:w-2/5 flex-wrap items-center text-base md:ml-auto">
                        <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900 cursor-pointer border-b border-transparent hover:border-indigo-600">Home</a>
                    </nav>
                    <a
                        className="flex order-first lg:order-none lg:w-1/5 title-font font-medium items-center lg:items-center lg:justify-center mb-4 md:mb-0">
                        <span className="ml-3 text-xl">L2 DEX HUB</span>
                    </a>
                    <div className="lg:w-2/5 inline-flex lg:justify-end ml-5 lg:ml-0">
                        <ConnectWallet />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </>
    )
}
```

`ConnectWallet.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import {ConnectMetamaskButton} from '../components/ConnectMetamaskButton';

export default function ConnectWallet(props) {
    const [Accounts, setAccounts] = useState("connect");
    console.log("1", Accounts);

    async function ConnectMetamask() {
        console.log("2", Accounts);

        try {
            const newAccounts = await ethereum.request({
                method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
            })

            let accounts = newAccounts;
            setAccounts({ accounts });
            console.log("accounts", accounts);
            console.log("3", Accounts.accounts);

            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
            console.log(provider);

            const signer = provider.getSigner(0);
            console.log(signer);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ConnectMetamaskButton Accounts = {Accounts} onClick={() => { ConnectMetamask(); }}></ConnectMetamaskButton>
        </div>
    );
};
```

`ConnectMetamaskButton`

```
export default function ConnectMetamaskButton(props) {
    return (
        <button className="btn-blue" onClick={ () => props.onClick()}>
            {props.Accounts}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Incidentally, in this implementation, the goal is to have the "wallet button" display the address name.

## error

However, when I `yarn dev`, I get the following error

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at ConnectWallet.jsx:35.
    at ConnectWallet (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/components/ConnectWallet.jsx:21:54)
    at div
    at div
    at header
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/components/Layout.jsx:16:3)
    at OutsideUsageExample
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.js:21:3)
    at AppContainer (/Users/tsudashouki/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:338:29)
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4053:17)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:626:31)
    at Function.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:193:19)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:68:29)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:643:40)
    at async doRender (/Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1127:38)
    at async /Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1221:28
    at async /Users/ts21/L2-DEX-HUB/client/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:60:36
```

I've checked the import/export relationship and the handling of props, but I can't find the problematic part. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
import ConnectMetamaskButton from '../components/ConnectMetamaskButton';
```

in `ConnectWallet.jsx`
as the error states `you might have mixed up default and named imports` and ConnectMetamaskButton is a default export

Comment: https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: I see. I didn't understand the meaning of {}.

Comment: As you pointed out, removing {} worked well. Also, changing it to setAccounts([ accounts ]); successfully achieved the goal!